# Codeigniter invalid upload path

Tags: php, codeigniter

Guys below is given code and folder structure. Anyone can please help me why it appearing "**The upload path does not appear to be valid.**" error? How can I resolve this error?

**Folder Structure**

```
Application
System
Upload
    414208
```

**Codeigniter Code:**

```
$config['upload_path']          = './uploads/414208';
$config['allowed_types']        = 'gif|jpg|png';
$this->load->library('upload', $config);
```

Comment: Because Your directory name is `Upload` and in your code you have specofy `uploads`  change it to `$config['upload_path']          = './Upload/414208';`

Answer (score 3):

your folder name is `Upload` and not `uploads`

use it like this

```
$config['upload_path'] = './Upload/414208/';
```

Answer (score 0):

As your upload location is outside of your application folder, something like this should work:

```
$config['upload_path'] = realpath(dirname(__FILE__)). '/Uploads/414208/';
```

if you decide to move your upload location within your application folder, then you can use APPPATH instead of realpath. If you use APPPATH, please note that it will have a trailing slash where realpath doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

**In you config**

```
$config['upload_path'] = './uploads/414208';
```

*it seems it cannot find directory named "uploads", this might be case sensitive and as ive been seeing in your Folder Structure you have Upload directory. You might want to rename your upload directory from "Upload" to "uploads" or change config upload path to './Upload/414208'*

Answer (score 0):

your folder name is Upload and you are writing 'upload'U must be capital

Answer (score 0):

This is because your folder name is "Upload" and you are using "uploads" in your upload_path

```
$config['upload_path'] = './Upload/414208/';
```