# File wont upload in CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, bootstrap-modal

I want to upload files via bootstrap modal . The file doesn't get uploaded I've tried several other methods I just get the same result.I should be able to upload pdf and images

Following is my controller

```
 public function add_file() {

    $config['upload_path'] = '/emp/uploads';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|jpeg|png|pdf';
    $config['max_size'] = 2048000;
    $config['max_width'] = 1600;
    $config['max_height'] = 1600;
    $config['encrypt_name'] = TRUE;
    $this->load->library('upload', $config);
    if (!$this->upload->do_upload('file')) {
        redirect('employees/display');
    } else {
        $data['emp_id'] = $this->input->post('emp');
        $data ['type'] = $this->input->post('type');
        $data ['file_name'] = $this->upload->data('file_name');
        $this->employee_model->insert_f($data);
    }
}
```

View:

```
  <form action="<?php echo base_url('employees/add_file'); ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <div class="modal fade" id="newmodal" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-header">
                                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Upload</h5>
                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                </button>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-body">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">File Type</label>

                                    <input type="text" name="type" class="form-control" >
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">File</label>

                                    <input type="file" name="file" size="20" class="form-control" >

                                </div>


                                <input type="hidden" name="emp"  class="form-control" value ="<?php echo$emp->emp_id ?>">
                                <input type="hidden" name="file_name"  class="form-control" >

                                <div class="modal-footer">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" name="submit"> Save</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </form>
```

model

```
 public function insert_f($data){
    $this->db->insert('emp_doc',$data);
  $id = $this->db->inser_id();
  return $id;
}
```

please help me out where have gone wrong

Comment: You can use `print_r($this->upload->display_errors());` to view errors. Most probably your path is incorrect.

Comment: i get Array ( [error] =>
The upload path does not appear to be valid.

i changed the path to ./uploads still same @sauhardnc

Comment: You have created a folder named `uploads`, right? This should be at the same place as your `application` folder

Comment: yes it is C:\htdocs\emp\uploads

Answer (score 0):

You should change your path to the uploads folder, like so -

```
$config['upload_path'] = './uploads';
```

or you can use -

```
$config['upload_path'] = realpath('uploads');
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45560666/codeigniter-invalid-upload-path) is a similar question regarding your issue.

This error can also occur if you're autoloading the `library`, so initializing it might solve your issue([Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8664758/the-upload-path-does-not-appear-to-be-valid-codeigniter-file-upload-not-worki)).

```
$this->load->library('upload', $config);
$this->upload->initialize($config);
```

See if it helps you.

Comment: Tried : 
Array
(
    [error] => <p>The upload path does not appear to be valid.</p>
)

Comment: @sarah I've updated my answer. If it doesn't fix your issue, please check the links I've mentioned in the question. There are multiple answers that just might help you. :)

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add one line pls add this lines add & then try.

```
$_FILES['upload_file'] = $_FILES['file'];
$config['file_name'] = $_FILES['upload_file']['name'];
```

if not then try from this link.

https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/file_uploading.html

Answer (score 0):

change your upload path a little bit like this.

```
$config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
```

don't forget the last /. see if it helps